# Remote validation with Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

I'm trying to implement remote validation for the email field in my (Django) form, but I'm getting the error "*Cannot read property 'addAsyncValidator' of undefined*".

The template (I'm using the [last dist of Parsley](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/88d99674a85d87a87b5ca887b68a3f35677e3883/dist/parsley.js), so the **remote.parsley.js** isn't needed)

```
<head>
<script src="{% static 'js/parsley.js' %}"></script>
</head> 

<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <input data-parsley-remote="/check_email/"
           data-parsley-remote-message="The introduced email has already been registered!"
           data-parsley-remote-options="{ 'type': 'POST' }"
           data-parsley-remote-validator="emailAvailable"
           data-parsley-remote-reverse="false"
           data-parsley-required="true"
           data-parsley-required-message="This field is required."
           data-parsley-trigger="change"
           data-parsley-type="email"
           id="id_email"
           name="email"
           required="required"
           type="email"
           value="a@a.com"/>

    {{ user_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

The script

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

$(function() {
            $("#user_form").parsley();
        });

        $('[name="email"]').Parsley.addAsyncValidator('emailAvailable', function (xhr) {
            var emailExists = this.$element.val().startsWith(xhr.responseJSON.email + "@");
            return !emailExists;
        }, '/check_email/');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`Parsley` is a global variable. You need to call `Parsley.addAsyncValidator(...)` to setup your custom function to analyse the result of ajax calls, but not `$somejQueryobject.Parsley.whatever`.

Comment: Hi, I'm a beginner with Javascript/JSON/etc.; since I've been struggling in the last few days with the issue, would you give me some hints on how to move to fully comprehend the issue and to build a custom client-side validation with Parsley.js (and Django)? Thank you!